# Add unique node names from a xml file into a list using c#

Tags: c#

Im using c# .net windows form application. I have a xml file. It has many nodes in it. Some nodes are repeated. I want to dispplay the nodes in a tree view. also I don't want repeated nodes.I need unique node name.
For example my xml file is this:
 
- 
- 
  abc 
  hello how ru 
  
- 
  def 
  i m fine 
  
- 
  ghi 
  how abt u

Now I want to display only:

languages
       language
          key 
          value
Similarly if there are any other unique nodes, I need to display them.
Please help me.

Comment: Could you give a more complete example of your XML?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <languages>
- <language>
  <key>abc</key> 
  <value>hello how ru</value> 
  </language>
- <language>
  <key>def</key> 
  <value>i m fine</value> 
  </language>
- <language>
  <key>ghi</key> 
  <value>how abt u</value> 
  </language>
  </languages>

Comment: Is this different from your previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771181/populate-a-tree-view-with-an-xml-file? At least the xml file is exactly the same...

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Linq2XML.

Comment: You can also load the full XML and then filter unique data.
You need to implement the IEqualityComparer interface and then use it on distinct operation.